# Assert equal time with some tolerance in phpunit

Tags: symfony, phpunit, test-double

I am just starting with phpunit and this is where I have little problem now.
The class I'm writing a test for, has a Logger method which when called, adds the timestamp to a property, Like this:

```
        $this->logger->info('Log created', [
        'user_id' => $order->getCustomerId(),
        'time' => microtime(true),
    ]);
```

Now in my test class after creating a new mock object of that class, this is how I check to see if some given mock data equals to my logger:

```
        $this->logger
        ->expects($this->once())
        ->method('info')
        ->with(
            $this->equalTo('Campaign code created'),
            $this->equalTo(['user_id' => 2000, 'time' => **??**])
        );
```

How can I change the question marks to assert this array equal to the time when it gets created? Or is there a way that I can't check this property at all? because right now without the time property it throws an error.

Answer (score 0):

There is `equalToWithDelta` which might actually work (it's essentially identical to [`assertEqualsWithDelta`](https://phpunit.readthedocs.io/en/9.5/assertions.html#assertequalswithdelta), the delta is just ignored for strings but applied to all numbers). However, since the delta is applied to all values of the array, this might pose a problem if you have something like ids in the array as well. So, depending on your test, that might be okay ...

However, there is also [`callback`](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/blob/5a201ebad9e5957a13cb9c23b5557c3c552b880a/src/Framework/Assert.php#L1953-L1963) which takes a function as an argument, which will allow you to make more sophisticated tests on the spot. Not done this but rather found in the source code, so I hope this solution is correct:

```php
$this->callback(function ($value) {
    return $value['user_id'] == 2000 
        && $value['time'] >= $minTime
        && $value['time'] <= $maxTime;
})
```

The class that is used by `callback` is the [`Callback` constraint](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/blob/5a201ebad9e5957a13cb9c23b5557c3c552b880a/src/Framework/Constraint/Callback.php#L40-L50)

You could also write a [custom comparator](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/comparator/blob/c53e48f3648e24898b2c74063cf892cb2f7e61e0/src/Factory.php#L79-L94), which I guess would go far and beyond the solution you're looking for.